# Sample space for: The probability that 4th power of a positive integer ends in the digit 6 is

Tags: probability

This was my test question, I marked `0.4` which was regarded correct but can't the answer be `0.5` because fourth power of every positive number ends with **0,1,6,5** .

Which is the correct answer and sample space ?

[The question in the title is word to word same]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note: the final digit of any power of an integer relies solely on the final digit of the original integer itself.

We have the following:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{original last digit}&\text{last digit of fourth power}\\
0&0\\
1&1\\
2&\color{blue}{6}\\
3&1\\
4&\color{blue}{6}\\
5&5\\
6&\color{blue}{6}\\
7&1\\
8&\color{blue}{6}\\
9&1\\
\hline\end{array}$

Since each final digit of the original integer is equally likely, the probability that the fourth power of a randomly selected integer being $6$ will be $\frac{\#\text{of choices that lead to final digit being 6}}{\#\text{of choices regardless}}=\frac{4}{10}=0.4$

(*The table is formed by considering $x^4\pmod{10}$ for each $x\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$*)

Comment: Does it mean that my saying, "*As it has four options and one of them 6 , therefore 0.25*" is entirely wrong ?

Comment: @DarshanJain The final digits of the fourth power of an integer are not equally likely.  You cannot say that since there are four final options that the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$.  See above, the final digit being $6$ occurs much more frequently than either of $0$ or $5$.  You may use $\frac{\#\text{of good options}}{\#\text{of options total}}$ for probability **ONLY** when the sample space is equiprobable.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. You saved my 4 marks :)

Comment: @DarshanJain Consider an extreme case.  You have a bag with a million white balls and one gold ball and you draw a ball at random.  There are only two "colors" of ball, so by the logic that there are two outcomes, white or gold, the one might think the probability of drawing a gold ball is $\frac{1}{2}$.  This is of course not the case as you will frequently draw a white ball instead.